# React peer dependency issue with enzyme-adapter-react-15.4

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am facing the peer dependency issue with `enzyme-adapter-react-15.4`. I use JEST along with ENZYME to unit test my React application. I use below config:

```
"react": "^15.1.0",
"enzyme": "^3.2.0",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
"enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "^1.0.5",
"react-dom": "^15.1.0",
```

And I get below errors even when I have all modules in place:

`! peer dep missing: react@15.0.0-0 - 15.4.x, required by enzyme-adapter-react-15.4@1.0.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-addons-test-utils@15.0.0-0 - 15.4.x, required by enzyme-adapter-react-15.4@1.0.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@15.0.0-0 - 15.4.x, required by enzyme-adapter-react-15.4@1.0.5`

I see in the node_modules/react/package.json that the version installed is 15.6.2 whereas I specifically installed 15.1 as prod dependency.

My config files:

```
// enzyme-setup.js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15.4';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**JEST:**

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./enzyme.setup.js",
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter",
    "coverageReporters": [
        "teamcity", "lcov"
   ],
    "rootDir": "",
    "roots": [
      "__tests__/unit/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "@PathToMappers(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/data/mappers/$1",
        "@PathToModels(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/data/models/$1",
        "@PathToMocks(.*)$": "<rootDir>/__tests__/mocks/data/$1",
        "@PathToXHRClient(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/service/xhr-client/$1",
        "@PathToComponents(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/component/$1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a setup configuration file for enzyme that should look like this:

```
//setup.js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Then you need to require this file in your jest object in your package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>" // path from your test folder to your setup.js file
  },
```

Comment: Try `import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';` instead of `import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15.4';`

Comment: But as per guidelines http://airbnb.io/enzyme/#installation, we need adapter 15.4 for react v 15.0.0-0 - 15.4.x.

Comment: @VishalGulati could you find out the correct way to setup with enzyme-adapter-react-15.4 ??

Comment: @Jhonatan I am currently away.Will get back in 2 days.